# How to select from list of items rendered using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having arrays of array as response

```
[
   [
     "i-091a5dosdobs2",
     "t2.nano",
     "running"
   ],
   [
     "i-03dd8duhud9",
     "t2.micro",
     "running"
   ]
]
```

I am using ng-repeat and rendering the data into table

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="datas in data" >
   <td ng-repeat="d in datas">
    {{d}}
   </td>
   <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(d)">Close</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I want button in all the rows which can able to close that particular instance but how to do it ?
in json we can do with key. How can I do it here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to pass the ec2 instance ID which is `d[0]`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(d[0])">Close</button>
```

and your close function would be like

```
$scope.close = function(id) {
   // factory send ajax to close the instance ... then
   let index = $scope.data.findIndex((i)=> i[0]===id)
   $scope.data.splice(index,1); // this would remove the item from your table
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) This is working I learned something new in angularjs  today

Answer (score 3):

If you need a unique key to close the row by it. Then you can use

```html
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
```

so the key will point to the index of the array 0, 1, 2, ...